# blazor webassembly multithreading mode update ui problem

Tags: multithreading, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I tested blazor webassembly to use with multithreading support coming with .net8 (and .net7 experimental)

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/mono/wasm/features.md
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/mono/wasm/threads.md#JS-interop-on-dedicated-threads

here is my basic code

```
<p role="status">Current text: @screenData</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ButtonClicked">Click me</button>

@code {
    private string screenData = "";

    private async void ButtonClicked()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message1,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        screenData = "AfterMessage1";

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message2,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Message3,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            await InvokeAsync(() => { screenData = "AfterMessage3"; Console.WriteLine("Message4,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); });

        });

        Console.WriteLine("Message5,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        screenData = "AfterMessage5";

    }
}
```

and here is the output on console while ui is not updating

```
Message1,MyThreadID:1
Message2,MyThreadID:2
Message3,MyThreadID:4
Message4,MyThreadID:4
Message5,MyThreadID:1
```

(Edit: i can see the ui label is updated as "AfterMessage5" when i click the button second time, but it is the result of the first click)

How can i invoke threadid1 (ui thread) from the child thread? (assuming i'm doing a long lasting (afew seconds) job background and want to update the ui with the results) Simply I could not figure out how to make the child threads talk to the ui thread

---

As a behavior info, when MultiThreading mode is enabled, even the following simple code does not update the label. Seems await creates a child thread. When multithreading is disabled that code works.

```
    private async void ButtonClicked()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        screenData = "Text To Label";
    }
```

---

Is there anyone who has experienced blazor wasm multithreading?

Regards

Ender

Comment: _"even the following simple code does not update the label."_ - just use `async Task` instead of `async void`. 2x

Comment: Ah yes thank you. it was the default sync IncrementCount click event of the button, comming with the default blazor template. just added an async to await Task.Run. Changed it to async Task now. but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I believe I answered another take on this question by Ender KARADAG here [How do child threads talk to the main (UI) thread in blazor webassembly (multithreading mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77590469/how-do-child-threads-talk-to-the-main-ui-thread-in-blazor-webassembly-multith/77590864#77590864)

Long story short, there is a bug in Blazor WASM ComponentBase.InvokeAsync which can be worked around at this time (workaround on other question answer.) I have also reported the bug on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95547).

Reply to this issue on GitHub:

> This is known gap. We didn't finish solving this problem on time to be included in Net8.