# How do child threads talk to the main (UI) thread in blazor webassembly (multithreading mode)

Tags: c#, multithreading, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Referencing my old post;

[blazor webassembly multithreading mode update ui problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589679/blazor-webassembly-multithreading-mode-update-ui-problem)

I am trying to use multithreading feature of blazor coming in .net8. Installed workloads and nugets as described. Enabled WasmEnableThreads

```
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly  

<p role="status">Current text: @screenData</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ButtonClicked">Click me</button>

@code {
    private string screenData = "";

    private async void ButtonClicked()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message1,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        screenData = "AfterMessage1";

        await Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message2,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            await Task.Delay(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Message3,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            await InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
               screenData = "AfterMessage3"; Console.WriteLine("Message4,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
               StateHasChanged(); 
            });

            await Task.Delay(2000);
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Message5,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        screenData = "AfterMessage5";

        StateHasChanged();

    }
}
```

When InvokeAsync(()=>StateHasChanged()) is called in a child thread, it doesn't run in main thread and so cannot update the UI and throws a javascript exception

```
System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Please use dedicated worker for working with JavaScript interop. See aka.ms/dotnet-JS-interop-threads)
```

Here is the console.WriteLine logs:

```
Message1,MyThreadID:1
Message2,MyThreadID:2
Message3,MyThreadID:4
Message4,MyThreadID:4
Message5,MyThreadID:1
```

As seen, Message4 is logged in InvokeAsync, but its threadid is 4 (runs in child thread)

When InvokeAsync is commented out here, Task runs, ui waits it to complete then updates itself with StateHasChanged. But that is not what i need.

---

Edit: I tried Dispatcher, but it seems to work in child thread also

```
   Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(async () =>{ });
```

---

Note that, when multithreading is disabled (default), this code works completely different

Is it possible to notify the ui thread (or invoke a code, call a method of ui thread etc) from child threads?

Regards

Ender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by @LoneSpawn provides an immediate answer to the issue and forms the basis for this answer.

This answer provides implementation details, additional information and speculation on the issue.

#### implementation:

Here's a modified `ComponentBase`.  It overloads the `InvokeAsync` methods to use a different `SynchronisationContext` [Any suggestions on improvements are welcome].

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace ThreadsTest.Pages;

public class WASMMultiThreadedComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    private SynchronizationContext _sc = SynchronizationContext.Current!;

    protected new Task InvokeAsync(Action action)
    {
        _sc.Post((object? state) => action(), null);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected new Task InvokeAsync(Func<Task> action)
    {
        _sc.Post((object? state) => action(), null);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

We can then use our refactored page:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Threading
@inherits WASMMultiThreadedComponentBase

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>@_log.ToString()</pre>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ButtonClicked">Click me</button>

@code {
    private System.Text.StringBuilder _log = new();

    private async Task ButtonClicked()
    {
        var message = "Button Clicked";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);

        await Task.Run(DoMessageAsync);

        message = "Button Clicked Completed";

        await LogMessageAsync(message);
    }

    private async Task DoMessageAsync()
    {
        var message = "DoMessageAsync started";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);

        await Task.Delay(500);
        message = "DoMessageAsync delay working...";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);

        await Task.Delay(500);
        message = "DoMessageAsync delay working...";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);

        await Task.Delay(500);
        message = "DoMessageAsync delay working...";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);

        await Task.Delay(500);
        message = "DoMessageAsync delay working...";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);

        await Task.Delay(500);
        message = "DoMessageAsync delay completed";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);

        await DoAfterMessageAsync();
    }

    private async Task DoAfterMessageAsync()
    {
        var message = "DoAfterMessageAsync started";
        await LogMessageAsync(message);
    }

    private async Task LogMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        var log = $"{message} - ThreadID:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";
        Console.WriteLine(log);

        _log.AppendLine(log);
        // ensure this is called on the Synchronisation Context
        await this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
        // Throw in an async yield to ensure the Renderer gets some thread time to render
        // if the code is running on that context
        // await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

### Details

I haven't delved too deeply into the code but it's apparent that we have two synchronisation contexts in play in the WASM context - see [JsSynchonisationContext](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/mono/wasm/threads.md#JS-interop-on-dedicated-threads).  The standard Blazor context and a `JsSynchonisationContext` for the JS context.  The Renderer creates a `Dispatcher` on the Blazor context that it passes to the component in the `RenderHandle` it passes in `Attach`.

That's not the `JsSynchonisationContext` we need. And that differs from the context returned by `SynchronizationContext.Current` which is [the context we need].  Add break points and you can check.

### Speculation

This is probably one of the reasons why multi-tasking in WASM is still experimental.  So much of Microsoft's Blazor code is dependant on `ComponentBase` [that it's coming back to haunt them].  It implements a hardwired `InvokeAsync` that doesan't work in the WASM multithreaded environment.

Comment: Thank you so much, this code looks clear. I used it just as u defined.

Now i need something similiar; assume we are doing a background job. At a point we want to ask for a user confirmation. Then background job will invoke main thread, wait for a reply and go on working due to the user selection (yes or no for this scenario). So we want to get a return value (bool) from the InvokeAsync function. (This may vary, that should accept object parameter and return an object back) I couldn't figure out how to implement it

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  This is a better solution I believe. Nice extra information also.

Comment: @EnderKARADAG - Can you please ask your "something similar" as another question?  It makes things easier to follow.

Comment: I solved it already and continued this post. Thank you for your help @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a bug in ComponentBase.InvokeAsync where it calls on the caller thread instead of the UI thread. I have reported this bug [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95547)

I created an alternative to InvokeAsync called InvokeAsyncAlt  that works by capturing the SynchronizationContext from the UI thread and then uses it to call back on the main thread.

```cs
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current text: @screenData</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ButtonClicked">Click me</button>

@code {
    private string screenData = "";
    
    private async void ButtonClicked()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message1,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        screenData = "AfterMessage1";

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message2,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            await Task.Delay(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Message3,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            await InvokeAsyncAlt(() =>
            {
                screenData = "AfterMessage3"; Console.WriteLine("Message4,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                StateHasChanged();
            });

            await Task.Delay(2000);
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Message5,MyThreadID:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        screenData = "AfterMessage5";

        StateHasChanged();

    }

    SynchronizationContext sctx = SynchronizationContext.Current!;
    async Task InvokeAsyncAlt(Action action)
    {
        sctx.Post((object state) => action(), null);
    }
    async Task InvokeAsyncAlt(Func<Task> action)
    {
        sctx.Post(async (object state) => await action(), null);
    }

}
```

Update: The reply to the issue I reported on GitHub:

> This is known gap. We didn't finish solving this problem on time to be included in Net8.

Comment: Thank you @LoneSpawn. This works like a charm!!!

Comment: This was a fun problem.  I am very much into Blazor WASM and threading. I wrote SpawnDev.BlazorJS.WebWorkers which is an alternative to real threads in Blazor WASM. It allows you to run Blazor services in web workers and call them directly. It supports .Net 6, 7, and 8 and works in any browser that supports workers. (Also supports running in a service worker.) I am very excited about real threading in Blazor so thanks for giving me a reason to take a look again. Glad to see they now support Firefox.

Comment: @LoneSpawn - Good solution, but I can't quite believe that there's such a fundamental bug in WASM multithreading.  The dispatcher is passed as a reference in the `RenderHandle`.  I find it hard to think that it's passing the wrong object.  Agree on the mental challenge, but I'm going to keep digging into the code and build a test component to see what it's passing as the Dispatcher.

Comment: Thank you so much @LoneSpawn. This fixed so much things for me. Additionaly how can we create a generic UIINVOKE method to call from everywhere. something like public async Task<object> UIInvokeOnMainThread(params object[] parameters)

Comment: Simply i want to return a value back to client thread that is invoking ui thread

Comment: @EnderKARADAG - see my answer on creating a new base component you can inherit from.  It overloads the base `InvokeAsync` methods.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @MrCakaShaunCurtis and @LoneSpawn i created a generic syncronous UI_INVOKE function fitting my need

It checks invoking method is awaitable or not, has a return value or void method. Accepts methodname to be invoked, multi parameters and returns an object (null if invoked function doesnt have a return type)

It has a while loop for awaitable methods, so shall be used at child threads only. If it is converted to an async method (or using a TaskCompletionSource) there wont be a need for a loop.

```
private SynchronizationContext sctx = SynchronizationContext.Current!;
private object UI_INVOKE(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{


    object res = null;

    var mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

    if (mi==null)
    {
        //method not found exception 
        return null;
    }

    var isAwaitable = mi.ReturnType.GetMethod(nameof(Task.GetAwaiter)) != null;

    if (isAwaitable)
    {
        bool completed = false;

        sctx.Post(async _ =>
        {

            if (mi.ReturnType.IsGenericType)
            {
                res = (object)await (dynamic)mi.Invoke(this, parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                await (Task)mi.Invoke(this, parameters);
            }

            completed = true;

        }, null);

        while (true)
        {
            if (completed == true)
                break;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sctx.Post(async _ =>
        {

            if (mi.ReturnType == typeof(void))
            {
                mi.Invoke(this, parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                res = mi.Invoke(this, parameters);
            }


        }, null);
    }

    return res;
}
```